# unknown sentence meaning/Czech equivalent

Tags: translation

What does this mean:

> intrinsic value of a state of affairs

Answer (score 1):

We need more context to really say.

"Intrinsic value" means the worth that something has of itself, from it's very nature. As opposed to worth that may be assigned to it by others or that it may acquire because of its relationship to something else. The distinction can be technical or debatable.

But for example, we might say that the intrinsic value of a letter opener is that it can be used to open envelopes. In another sense we might say that it's intrinsic value is $5. But if you learn that this letter opener was owned by Winston Churchill and was the letter opener that he used to open some historic document, it may sell at auction for a large sum of money.

The intrinsic value of a key is very small. But if that key can be used to open a box that contains valuable jewels, then the key takes on much greater value.

Et cetera.

(Financial people have a technical definition of "intrinsic value of an asset", probably not relevant here.)

A "state of affairs" is the way things are now (or were at, at some time under discussion). Like you might say that the "current state of affairs of Chinese-American relations is guarded".

So "the intrinsic value of a state of affairs" would be what the way things are right now is worth. Without some context its difficult to say exactly what the writer means by that.